# PHPMailer - attachment from the contact form

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem with the addition attachment to the PHPMailer. I need that this attachment was loaded from input so could only upload files. Doc,. Docx,. Pdf, and after all, it is sent to the mail.

Link to some example you can, because what I find it does not work for me, something I have done wrong - just do not know what :/

Waiting for your reply

Comment: Please post, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by reading the examples provided with PHPMailer, like [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps). Saying 'it doesn't work' isn't going to get you any help on here. Provide more detail, post your code.